# holder is MyView from C# to Java

Tags: java, android

```
holder is MyView
MyView myHolder = holder as MyView;
```

and

I am trying to change my Xamarin project to an android app using java`
And getting errors on how to use 'is' and 'as' in Android. Need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java you do not cast an object to another super/subclass by using "is" or "as". Instead, you put a bracket.

```
holder as MyView;
```

should instead be

```
(MyView) holder
```

Comment: What about for 'is' because when i used it in this case if(holder is MyView) and i use it as if((MyView)holder) and i get incompatible types

Comment: if(holder instanceof MyView)